# I believe I've deleted MySQL root user, how do I recreate it?

Tags: centos, mysql, root

I'm running ISPConfig on CentOS and I don't know how, but I don't seem to have a root mysql user.

I can stop mysqld with

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

Start it again and skip grant tables

```
mysqld_safe --skip_grant_tables &
mysql> SELECT * FROM sql.user
```

I see 4 users I had previously created but no root user.
I tried putting this in a file /root/rootreset.sql.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And starting with that file

```
mysqld_safe --init-file=/root/rootreset.sql &

[1] 30039
[root@algrhckdj ~]# Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql/
STOPPING server from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
111020 04:06:34  mysqld ended
[1]+  Done                    mysqld_safe --init-file=/root/rootreset.sql
```

It looks like the sql was executed, I don't see an error, but the service doesn't seem to be running, I can't connect to it without this error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
```

I tried running the sql from the console after starting with `--skip-grant-table` but got this error.

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

This seems like a lot of info but I've been trying all the different suggestions online and can't get anywhere. What should I be doing?

Help me superuser, you're my only hope.

Comment: Please answer your own question using the button below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed these [instructions](http://web.archive.org/web/20101114072725/http://devlog.info/2010/10/12/restoring-a-deleted-mysql-root-user/) and my root user is now listed in the user table and I can login with it. What seemed to do it was performing these steps as the mysql user rather than root.

```
root# /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
root# su mysql
mysql$ pwd
/home/mysql
mysql$ echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;"> mysql-init
mysql$ mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/mysql/mysql-init &
mysql$ rm mysql-init
mysql$ mysql -uroot -p   # woot, works
```

Comment: Feels great to solve your own problems, eh? +1 !!!