# Cannot use mysql after removing root user from mysqld

Tags: mysql

I accidently removed root user from mysqld:

DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Now I am unable to do anything (as expected), but I would like to understand the recovery steps. How to continue now, or am I doomed?

I've even followed the steps from another thread ([I believe I've deleted MySQL root user, how do I recreate it?](https://superuser.com/questions/348733/i-believe-ive-deleted-mysql-root-user-how-do-i-recreate-it)), but it doesn't work either

Basically I would like to know how to start afresh, if possible

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
Stop MySQL service.
Run mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
Type mysql -u root -p and press enter.
Enter your password.
At the mysql command line enter: use mysql;
```